# Code disappears in vs2010

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

I was writing the c# code in vs2010, suddenly the light went out. When I restarted my system and opened my project in vs2010 and opened my class (.cs) file, a blank notepad window appear and nothing happens although the size of code file is 18.2KB. I changed the default editor, but my code  wouldn't appear. I need some assisstance.

Comment: What do you see if you open the .cs file in Notepad?

Comment: Can you try opening the file with another editor (Notepad, Notepad++)?

Comment: Did u try opening file in simple notepad???

Comment: Once something like that occered to me i lost the code. Then i bought ups.

Comment: I see nothing in simple notepad file, its blank\

Comment: Buy a ups for the next time. Till then save your code frequently.

Comment: I have dll file of the source code. Is there any way, i can decompile it?

Comment: search on google "[decompiler](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=decompiler&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:en-GB:official&client=firefox-a)" (I've used jetbrains before)

Comment: use reflector `http://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/reflector/`

Comment: I have installed .net reflector 8.1, I selected my project .dll file. but it does not decompile my class source code. How should I do it ?

Comment: @user2199343 - Fix the errors that prevent the code from being able to compile.  I have no idea why this question was migrated from Stackoverflow.  **If your source file is empty then the code is gone**

Comment: Something I missed?  Has source control gone out of fashion while I wasn't paying attention?  This kind of painful code loss is what's always required to get a programmer to start considering source control.

Answer (score 3):

Sounds like the file is corrupted. It may be showing the incorrect file size. Quick test - zip it (or rar) and see what the new files size is and compare it to the non-compressed file. If it's compressed to nearly nothing, that is a good indication (I had the same, a 2gb file compressed to a few MB).

However, my money is on it being corrupted, restore the file from a back up if you can, or start rewriting, or use something like dotPeek to see if you can salvage your .DLL file.